# Turning Off/Altering Eclipse Prediction

Tags: eclipse

When coding Java in Eclipse, it often tries to predict what you're typing. For instance in GWT's UiBinder, I just tried `<g:Rad` and then it took around 15 seconds for it to often me 'RadioButton' whilst not allowing me to type the bloody thing in. Whilst it's an extremely useful thing, my system is mobile and isn't particularly fast, therefore I'd rather explicity do a `ctrl + space` to ask Eclipse to offer me what I might want.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content assist   you can uncheck the Enable Auto-Activation there, or reduce the time to 0ms so it assists you immediately